Parametric Curve
Evaluate the following double integral: $I=\iint_{D}^{}y dydx$ with the region $D$ defined by $\left\{\begin{matrix}
x=R(t-sint) &  & \\ 
y=R(1-cost), y=0 & & \\ 
 0\leq t\leq 2\pi&  & 
\end{matrix}\right.$
I'm quite curious about how to convert differential $dxdy$ to differential $dt$.
Can I do the following?
$dx=R(1-cos(t))dt=ydt\Rightarrow I=\iint_{D}^{}y^{2} dydt$
Thank you for taking the time to read this article of mine. Hope everyone can help me with this question

No. This does not work. Your equation for $dx$ is valid only on the curve. The parametrization, together with $y=0$, gives the boundary of the region.  Perhaps you should use Green’s Theorem?

Similar problem
